# Double tap using Appium Java 2.0

Tags: appium

I couldn't find an implementation of a double tap for Appium that was straightforward and allowed you to pass in the element locator strategy, so here goes:

```
public static void doubleTapElementBy(By by) {
        WebElement el = getDriver().findElement(by);
        MultiTouchAction multiTouch = new MultiTouchAction(getDriver());
        TouchAction action0 = new TouchAction(getDriver()).tap(el).waitAction(50).tap(el);
        try {
            multiTouch.add(action0).perform();
        } catch (WebDriverException e) {
            logger.info("Unable to do second tap on element, probably because element requieres single tap on this Android version");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am clueless as to what Appium even is, but in case no one else knows, you could wait a little bit before handling the tap to check if another one will follow closely. In more detail you can use a timer to trigger the handling something like 0.2 seconds later, and also have a variable counting the taps in the same location (obviously it won't be exactly the same, but you get the idea). Would that work?

Comment: I'm not sure how your idea would work as both commands are chained into a multi touch action rather than one at a time. Feel free to post code though. thanks

Comment: I'll try it in pseudocode:
    Interpretmessages(){ switch(msg){
    OnClick: {
    if (lastClicked - thisTime() < 0.2){doubleTapped()}
    else{lastClicked = thisTime()} } //end of OnClick
    } //End of Message Handler

If you have access to ready timer functions, you can set a function to be executed 0.2s after the click has gone off:
    OnClick: if (!functionWaiting) // has the timer not been set?
    {enableTimer(); clicks = 0} //set it for the first click
    clicks++; //if it's already clicked, notify that there's been another one, otherwise it'll know it's one click

Comment: I am terribly sorry about the fact that it got messed up, I never understood how to get code into comments.. It should work for clicks and taps alike though

Comment: I found a workaround :) https://www.pastevault.com/view/a167df9ebc5ed6dcf6c555b9d1b94145 with the decryption Password: stackoverflow

Comment: You can just add your own answer so the code would be formatted properly and it wouldn't have users have to go to an external site

Comment: Wouldn't an answer with a workaround in pseudocode be frowned upon? But on the other hand since there's no other answer I guess the "better than nothing" philosophy takes over, so I'll do that, sorry for delaying the process..

Answer (score 1):

You can also try below approach using tap method in TouchAction class.

```
    TouchAction taction = new TouchAction(driver);

    taction.tap(tapOptions().withElement(ElementOption.element(YOUR_WebElement))
   .withTapsCount(2)).perform();
```

You will need to add below static import as well:

```
import static io.appium.java_client.touch.TapOptions.tapOptions;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround in pseudocode and possibly there's a more "official" way to do it, but it should do the work if no other solution is available:

```
Interpretmessages(){ 
switch(msg)
{ 
    OnClick: 
    { if (lastClicked - thisTime() < 0.2) //if it was clicked very recently
        {doubleTapped()} //handle it as a double tap
      else{lastClicked = thisTime()}  //otherwise keep the time of the tap
        } //end of OnClick 
    } //End of Message Handler
}//End of switch
}//End of messageHandler
```

If you have access to ready timer functions, you can set a function to be executed 0.2s after the click has gone off:

```
OnClick: if (!functionWaiting) // has the timer not been set? 
{
    enableTimer(); // set a function to go off in x time
    clicks = 0; //we'll tell it that there's been one click in a couple of lines
} //set it for the first click 
clicks++; //if it's already clicked, it'll become 2 (double tap) otherwise it's just one
```

So, the idea is that when you get a tap, you check if there's been another one recently (a. by checking the relative times, b. by checking if the function is still pending) and you handle it dependingly, only note that you will have to implement a timer so your function fires a bit later so you have time to get a second tap

The style draws upon the Win32's message handling, I'm pretty sure it works there, it should work for you too.

Answer (score 0):

Double tap and hold -- Use below code:

```
new TouchAction(driver).press(112,567).release().perform().press(112,567).perform();
```

Double tap -- Use below code:

```
new TouchAction(driver).press(112,567).release().perform().press(112,567).release().perform();
```